# When running Hangfire background tasks on IIS with HttpClient then task is imediately cancelled, why?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, hangfire, polly, cancellation-token

This is a bit frustrating, one of those cases where there are no problems running localhost but after deploying to IIS threading exceptions start to creep in.

Anyway, I'm using Hangfire v1.7.11 with SQLServer as it's backend storage.

The job in question is setup with:

```
    await Task.Run(() =>
        _jobClient.AddOrUpdate<ILiveDataService>(
            notification.BmUnitGuidId.ToString(),
            d => d.UpdateBmUnit(notification.BmUnitGuidId, CancellationToken.None),
            "* * * * *"),
        cancellationToken);
```

The important part here being the `CancellationToken.None` passed in as per Hangfire docs.

The `ILiveDataService` is making use of an HttpClient setup in an HttpClientFactory in my `startup.cs` file, I'm just substituting in `IDummyClient` here. This should be doing the generic setup of baseUri and authentication headers. There is also a Transient Http Error Policy to handle flaky connections.

```
    services.AddHttpClient<IDummyClient, DummyClient>(
        c =>
        {
            c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["DummyClient:Url"]);
            var authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(Configuration["Dummy:User"] + ":" + Configuration["Dummy:Password"]));
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authInfo);
        })
        .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
        {
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        }));
```

Within the DummyClient the method being called is:

```
    public async Task<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double?>> GetValues(string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dateFrom = RoundUp(this.DateTimeUtc, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        using var response = await this._httpClient.GetAsync(
                $"{paramterisedurl}",
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                cancellationToken);

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
             var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
             xmlDocument.Load(stream);

             // Process horrendous XML response - it's too ugly to share :-)

             return new KeyValuePair<DateTime, double?>(default, default);        
        }

        var content = await StreamToStringAsync(stream);

        throw new ApiException
        {
            StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
            Content = content
        };
    }
```

As far as I can tell from the exception message in Hangfire the job is dying during the `GetAsync()` call. The trace from Hangfire is as follows:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
The operation was canceled.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`5 onRetryAsync, Int32 permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4 sleepDurationProvider, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy`1.ExecuteAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Infrastructure.Sentinel.SentinelClient.GetBoaPhysicalNotification(String bmUnitName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Sentinel/SentinelClient.cs:line 97
   at ApplicationCore.ApplicationServices.LiveDataService.LiveDataService.UpdateBmUnit(Guid bmUnitGuidId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/ApplicationCore/ApplicationServices/LiveDataService/LiveDataService.cs:line 81
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

Though what I find to be unusual is that the Job info that Hangfire shows details the `CancellationToken` as being `null`...

```
// Job ID: #140
using ApplicationCore.ApplicationServices.LiveDataService;

var liveDataService = Activate<ILiveDataService>();
await liveDataService.UpdateBmUnit(
    FromJson<Guid>("\"fa832ce4-b2a5-47d1-9b04-6ffb52fa0f30\""),
    null);
```

I imagine there are many issues here that could be causing this to fail, but fundamentally it would appear to that the `CancellationToken` isn't correctly being passed down into the method and as soon as it is checked, in the `ConnectAsync` the thing unravels.

As I said earlier this doesn't occur on localhost... only on deployment.

Comment: [`HttpClient` expresses a timeout as an `TaskCanceledException`](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/).  Is it possible that the initial connection attempt is simply timing out?

Comment: Cheers, it was actually an authorization issue on the production server :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally this was an issue with the production server not being authorised to make the same calls that the localhost machine was.

However the exception thrown in the client was masked by the generic exception being thrown so a little tricky to diagnose.

Resulting diagnosis was from logging into the production box and trying to run the basic http request with Curl.

Second lesson is to assume nothing :-)